# Vue 2 <transition mode=out-in> not transitioning the first element

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, css-transitions

Using Vue 2.6.14 I am toggling between two buttons using v-if and v-else. I wrapped everything inside a transition but the first element never transitions, not in nor out.

```html
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <TappaPaginazione v-if="!$store.state.modal.isOpen" :key="$route.params.slug"/>
  <button v-else @click="toggleModal(null)" class="btn">Chiudi</button>
</transition>
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  @apply transition-opacity duration-500 ease-in-out;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it actually was the `display: contents;` I gave to the custom component. I guess it cant be transitioned

Comment: SO tells me I have to wait for 2 days

Comment: @StefanGarofalo have you tried to use the appear prop on the transition component as specified in the docs ?
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitions-on-Initial-Render

Comment: @GeorgesA yes but to no avail